# Detect if all pixels in an image are zero/black (Maya Python)

Tags: python, performance, pixel, maya, pyside2

Newbie. Using the following code to check if a grayscale image (a mask texture in Maya) has all black pixels in the RGB channels (meaning it is empty). This works, but is a bit slow on large images (2048x2048 is around 15 seconds). Looking for how I can speed this up / do this more efficiently.

EDIT: This is the original code

```
def all_black_pixels(image, width, height):
    img = PySide2.QtGui.QImage(width, height, PySide2.QtGui.QImage.Format.Format_Grayscale8)
    img.load(image)     
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            color = PySide2.QtGui.QColor()
            color.setRgb(img.pixel(x,y))  
            black = False
           # print ( color.getRgb()[0] )
            if color.getRgb()[0] is not 0:
                black = True
   
    return black
```

EDIT: changing based on comments, for clarity and fixing:

```
import PySide2

def all_black_pixels(image):
    black = True
    img = PySide2.QtGui.QImage()
    img.load(image)
    TexSize = img.width()     
    for y in range(TexSize):
        for x in range(TexSize):
            color = PySide2.QtGui.QColor()
            color.setRgb(img.pixel(x,y))  
            print ( color.getRgb()[0] )
            if color.getRgb()[0] > 0:
                black = False
                break
   
    return black

all_black_pixels('/path/to/file/fileName.jpg', 20, 20)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it will work as intended - it will return True if the last pixel in the image is black, False otherwise

Comment: what is `image`? is an array? a file name? wich libraries are you willing to use?

Comment: @stuart thanks, I edited it adding a break so it will hopefully now work.

Comment: @UlisesBussi I edited the code showing that the image is a file name. Ideally I'd like to use libraries that are installed with Maya's Python, and avoid additional modules that I'd need to compile, such as PIL

Comment: @sharktacos Is there anything special about your image files, or will any jpg do for the purposes of testing? Can you provide a suitable sample?

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for your contribution, it's much appreciated! To answer your question, the files are 8-bit black and white JPG or PNG. They can be greyscale (red channel only) or possibly R=G=B. I've tested all these types and thanks to the ```img.convertTo(img.Format_Grayscale8)``` step in the updated answer from @musicamente these all are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `image` is an iterable byte object (`bytes` or `bytearray`), you can cycle through its values instead of making things more complex than they should: images are "collections of bytes", so, converting those collections to "actual" images and getting their pixel values makes very little sense.

Since you have to know if *any* of the pixels has a "non-black" color, you don't need to always iterate the whole image: yes, you have to iterate through the whole image because even the "last" pixel could be "non-black", but, as soon as *any* previous pixel isn't black, there's obviously no point in checking the next ones.

The assumption is:

- 8-bit grayscale images always use a single byte for each pixel;
- if the pixel is black, the value of the byte is 0;

Also, knowing the size of the image is useless.

So, just call the function only using the raw data alone:

```py
def all_black_pixels(imageData):
    for pixel in imageData:
        if pixel:
            return False
    return True
```

Even simpler:

```py
all_black_pixels = lambda imageData: not any(imageData)
```

### Update

Since the OP has changed the question pointing out they start from an image *file*, the solution is similar, but it uses [`constBits()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#constBits), which returns an array of the image *data*.

Consider that this is on the assumption that the image format is `Format_Grayscale8`, if it's not, it should be converted before with [`convertTo()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#convertTo).

Also note that if you use PyQt, the returned type of `constBits()` is a sip pointer, so it must be converted to an actual array that can be accessed by python.

```py
def all_black_pixels(path):
    img = QImage(path)
    if img.isNull():
        return False # or whatever you think appropriate

    if not img.format() == img.Format_Grayscale8:
        img.convertTo(img.Format_Grayscale8)

    # for PySide
    return not any(img.constBits())
    # for PyQt
    return not any(img.constBits().asarray(img.sizeInBytes()))
```

Comment: @musicamente Love the elegant simplicity! However, the code is not working for me. Likely it's me being a noob. For "imageData" I currently have a file name which does not work. What do I need to do to get that file name into an "iterable byte object"?

Comment: @sharktacos what about just using a basic python `with open('<path/to/image>') as f:` `print(all_black_pixels(f.read()))`?

Comment: @musicamente that gives me this error:
```# Error: UnicodeDecodeError: file /Applications/Autodesk/maya2022/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/codecs.py line 322: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte #```

Comment: @musicamente Update: fixed the error by declaring it as a binary with ```with open('<path/to/image>', 'rb') as f: ``` however the code always returns "False" now even when feeding it an image that should return "True"

Comment: Surely most image files will include more than just pixel-data, so it seems unlikely that directly reading the bytes will produce reliable results.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yeah, right, I was too tired and commented without thinking.

Comment: It would help a lot if the OP would provide a sample image file so we can do some proper testing.

Comment: @ekhumoro if the image is 8-bit grayscale, it should be enough to use `not any(qimage.bits().asarray(qimage.width() * qimage.height()))`, right? And if it's not, it would be probably faster to first convert it to `Format_Grayscale8` than iterating through pixels in python.

Comment: @musicamante I was thinking `not any(img.constBits().asarray( img.sizeInBytes()))`, since it doesn't make a copy.

Comment: @sharktacos Sorry for the misleading suggestion. See the update.

Comment: @musicamante I just noticed the OP is using pyside, which uses a different memory-pointer type. This means the code can be reduced to `not any(img.constBits())`.

Comment: @musicamante brilliant! Works perfectly and returns super fast! Thanks for your help. I learned a ton :)