# Detect if all pixels in an image are the same color/value (Maya Python)

Tags: python, maya, pyside2

Follow-up question from previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73298238/detect-if-all-pixels-in-an-image-are-zero-black-maya-python). This code detects if all pixels in an image (8-bit greyscale jpg) are zero/black, using Pyside:

```
def all_black_pixels(path):
img = QImage(path)
if img.isNull():
    return False # or whatever you think appropriate

if not img.format() == img.Format_Grayscale8:
    img.convertTo(img.Format_Grayscale8)

# for PySide
return not any(img.constBits())
```

Would like to adapt this to check if all pixels in a channel are the same value. Solid red or solid grey, a flat constant color.

For example, on a bump map in L8 format (8-bit luminance) the pixels would be 50% grey on the red channel and black on green and blue, RGB[0.5, 0, 0]. On a normal map they would be RGB[0.5, 0.5, 1] (assuming a 0-1 RGB scale).

FWIW this is a height/bump map texture Output from Substance 3D Painter, and the Pyside2 would be running inside of Maya.

Comment: The concept is the same, only you have to check for "triplets" of values. I'm not familiar with the formats you're using, but I suppose that the "actual" result doesn't change the original values of those channels as byte values, right?

Comment: Also, what is the Qt format for those images? Is it `QImage.Format_RGB888`? Use `print(int(img.format()))` and compare the result with the [QImage format table](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#image-formats).

Comment: @musicamante yes I believe so. I've uploaded two sample JPEGs here https://github.com/sharktacos/VFX-software-prefs/tree/main/Maya/scripts/SubstancePainterToMaya/bump2

Comment: @musicamante the format on the JPEGS is 24 which would be QImage::Format_Grayscale8. 
Incidentally, I originally attempted to do this with 32bit float TIFF files, but was getting a Null and Format.Invalid on them.

Comment: I believe that your next to last paragraph was a bit misleading to me: so you're still working with the same format, the only difference with your previous question was that now you want to know if the bump surface is *flat* (no matter its color/depth) instead of just black?

Comment: @musicamante Apologies for any confusion. Yes, it is the same format image, but instead of black/0 returning a "true" I want it to return "true" if all of the pixels in a channel are the exact same value. A constant color detection. All grey, all red, etc. Thus in the example JPG I posted called "flat" the pixels are all the same (true) whereas in the JPG called "bump" the image has different pixel values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't differ that much from your previous question, as we don't really care about the representation of the image but only about its pixel values: as soon as *any* value is different from the *first* one, we know that the image has more than one "color".

```py
def all_pixels_identical(path):
    img = QImage(path)
    if img.isNull():
        return False # or whatever you think appropriate

    if not img.format() == img.Format_Grayscale8:
        img.convertTo(img.Format_Grayscale8)

    # for PySide
    it = iter(img.constBits())
    # for PyQt
    it = iter(img.constBits().asarray(img.sizeInBytes()))

    first = next(it)
    while True:
        try:
            if first != next(it):
                return False
        except StopIteration:
            return True
```

<sup>Note: I hadn't had the chance to test the code, so it's possible that it needs some fixing, but the concept is fundamentally correct. OTOH, I'd suggest you to do some research on how raster images are represented as raw data in memory, so that you could better understand such matters in the future.</sup>

Comment: @musicamente Yes I'd love to understand that better. If there are any resources you can recommend I'm eager to learn!

Comment: Well, you can begin with the basic [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics) which is a good start.

Comment: Much simpler (and about twice as fast on my system): `bits = img.constBits(); a = bits[0]; all(a == b for b in bits)`.